# Unable to use ngx-mqtt for angular 10 app

Tags: angular, mqtt, iot, angular10

Perhaps, I should start with the fact that this is the first time I am working with mqtt. I am web-developer and starting first ever IoT thing.

So, I researched and found that:

1. MQTT protocol is not directly supported by browsers.
2. However MQTT can be integrated with browser over a WS protocol.

(Would like if anyone can validate these facts or point any errors.)

Having said this, I tried using `ngx-mqtt` npm [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mqtt) with my angular-10 app. However, I have not been able to install it successfully[image].

I keep getting below errors even after cleaning node modules and re-installing everything.

I have gone through various articles (for instance [this](https://bugfender.com/blog/using-mqtt-on-angular-apps/) one here) but haven't been able to achieve my connection with device.

Can someone please:

1. Help me fix the error with the above npm module.
2. Direct me to an example/blog/working-demo of a angular-mqtt
   integration.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have a look at this Github issues: https://github.com/sclausen/ngx-mqtt/issues/169 https://github.com/sclausen/ngx-mqtt/issues/171

Comment: Use previous version :  npm i --save ngx-mqtt@7.0.9

Comment: Thanks guys. I was able to install @7.0.9. Going ahead with this https://bugfender.com/blog/using-mqtt-on-angular-apps/ , now I get an error `util.js:103 Uncaught ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined
    at Object.Onz0 (util.js:103)`. Any resolutions?

Comment: Nevermind, Requiring buffer module in polyfill.ts seems to cover the above issue.

Comment: The issues should now be resolved with ngx-mqtt and it should be able to be installed without any polyfills